# Docker desktop vs docker.io

Tags: linux, debian, docker

Can I run docker CLI installed from `docker.io` & docker desktop simultaneously on a Linux machine? I know it's not optimal but I was doing this in the past and it was working just fine. But recently the newest `apt-update` removed the `docker-desktop` & kept the `docker.io`. If so how can I migrate my `docker.io` containers to `docker-desktop`?